# (Django) DataFieldTime always returns 00:00:00.000000

Tags: mysql, django

I'm trying to set a created_data and modify_data using datetimefield as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4ni5.png)

but I added a value to the database, always return  00:00:00.000000 as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGF5v.png)

Why is this?
And I'd appreciate it if you could help me figure it out.
I searched the web for an hour, but I couldn't find the answer...

Comment: Instead of images post code as text

Answer (score 0):

[`Datefield`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#datetfield) is a date representation

> A date, represented in Python by a datetime.date instance.

you should use [`DateTimeField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield) instead

> A date and time, represented in Python by a datetime.datetime instance

Answer (score 0):

`DateTimeField` validate and returns date and time

`DateField` validate and returns just date

try this :

```
create_date = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
modify_date = DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```